# Number of the places listed at a specific bbox

Tags: here-api, bounding-box

Currently having a problem about the number of the results when I search for the places by using bbox coordinates of an area.

My questions are:

1) Is there any solution to get more than 80 results per search? -might be 500 max-

2) (This question is for https://developer.here.com/) If there are more than 80 places at a specific bbox how do you select the results you list-because you list max. 80 of them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On their page they already say they only list "popular places" within a specified area.

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/places/explore-places-bounding-box

They explain how "popularity" is being calculated as well. "The popularity of the result, e.g. number of clicks, number of times it has been saved as a "favorite".

https://developer.here.com/cn/documentation/places/topics/search-results-ranking.html

The conclusion is if you are using Search (Places) API by using bounding box coordinates of an area and if bounding box has more than 80 places in it, results are pretty inaccurate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite general. Let me answer it this way, with the REST API, there's a parameter 'size' which specifies "The maximum number of result items in each collection." (note you are not guaranteed to always get back that many POIs). 
There should be similar parameters in the SDK or other ways of accessing the search system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am talking about "Exploring the places within a bounding box"  right here: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/places/explore-places-bounding-box so only parameters I see here 1) in 2) app id and 3) app code. I am having difficulty to get all the results in a specific bbox coordinate which I know it has btw 400-500 places in it. I get max 80 of them. I am wondering how to change the number of results in Search (Places) API?